# JSONObject arrayList parsing in php

Tags: php, android, json

I am new to JSON. KIndly help me with the JSON parsing in php sent from android.

I have a class A, having members phoneNumber and name. I have an `arrayList` of object **A**

```
    private ArrayList<A> contactList = new ArrayList<A>();
    contactList.add(a1);
    contactList.add(a2); [objects of A]
```

Now I am trying to send this arrayList to php server using JSON.

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
json.put("contactList", contactList);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("");
StringEntity se = new StringEntity("JSON: " + json.toString());
post.setEntity(se);
HttpResponse resP = client.execute(post);
```

Please let me know how to I parse it in the php server side to get phoneNumber and name of each object **A**.

I tried to create a same class **A** in the php server side and trying this way.

```
<?php
    $contactList = array();
    if(isset($_POST["contactList"])) {
        $contactList = json_decode($_POST["contactList"]);
        include_once './eachContactClass.php';
        foreach ($contactList->contactList as $eachContact) {
            $eachObj = new eachContactClass();
            $eachObj = $eachContact;
            $name = $eachObj->getName();
            $phoneNumber = $eachObj->getPhone();

        }
    }
```

Please let me know whether the approach is correct, or kindly help me to correct it

Answer (score 0):

First of all, may I suggest you to use a library for handling the JSON serialization/deserialization. [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) would be suited for your work.

Then, you should check the result JSON for validity before sending it to any remote server.

To parse it in PHP, use the [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.json-decode.php) function that will return your an object representing your JSON. You can also get a hash if you prefer, just look in the doc.

I think your problem is that your JSON is invalid, as the JSONObject doesn't correctly serialize your ArrayList. Your should probably check that.